# Print stylesheet in Next.js 10

Tags: css, next.js, print-style

In my Next 10 application, I can import global styles in `_app.js` like so

```
import 'assets/css/app.css'
```

I'd like to add a print stylesheet. I know I can use a `@media print { }` query to `app.css`, but  ideally it would be loaded as a separate file so the download priority is lower, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/print.css" media="print">
```

Is this possible using Next.js? I can't see any obvious way to control how the actual `<link>` tag is rendered.

The only way I can see this *might* work is to have a custom bit of Webpack/file-loader configuration that matches `print.css` only, which feels... less than ideal.

Comment: Please show us the rest of your JSX code and your NextJS page render function.

Comment: You should be able to use `next/Head` and return a `<Head>` JSX element with that `<link />` inside of it. See here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

Comment: Sure, but is there any way to get a link to that stylesheet via `import` other than putting it in the public folder?

Comment: If it wasn’t in a public folder, how else would browsers be able to download it?

Comment: I'd like it to go through the same build process that the rest of the CSS files use, so it gets a hashed identifier for cacheability etc and ends up in the `_next/static/css` folder like the other stylesheets that get generated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question as you velvetkevorkian but with the intend to use the following technique:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webfonts.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
```

This will indeed lower the priority in the loading queue, prevent rendering from being blocked and finally replace the native fonts by the webfonts.

UPDATE: not ideal but for my *"simple"* CSS file (which only defines `font-face`) here is what I did:

1. Move my `webfonts.css` file to the public folder
2. Manually add my `<link>` inside `<Head>`

Comment: Yeah, ideally it would go through the build process for cacheability etc

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, yes!

You can create Print.module.css in folder **pages** or **anywhere**, inside of this file you must use

```
@media print {
     /* its an example */
    .noPrint{
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Inside your file .js or .tsx you call this css like a

```
import print from './Print.module.css'
```

and call the className like:

```
className={print.noPrint}
```

if you have more stylesheets in your project you can differenciate like this:

```
import print from './Print.module.css'
import styles from './General.module.css'
```

and call the classes together, it goes like this:

```
className={`${styles.anyclass} ${print.anyclass}`}
```

this works too for responsive stylesheets, enough follow this logic with respectives media queries.

Comment: This won't output it as a separate stylesheet though will it? I'm looking for a separate link tag with media="print" on it.

Comment: will generate yes with this my example, however you can use the same stylesheet, the core is in the CSS in the media query @media print {}

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in the question "I know I can use a `@media print { }` query to app.css, but ideally it would be loaded as a separate file so the download priority is lower"